# fetch a foreign key data from mysql database into select dropdownlist using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to create a select dropdownlist which retrieves data from a table "teamtable" and displays it on a page where the user enters his choice and the corresponding ID for the choice is submitted in other database "user" where the column is a foreign key.

Tables and their contents-

**teamtable**-

idTeam(INT)(PK) - 1,2,3

teamName(VARCHAR) - Team-1, Team-2, Team-3

**user**-

team(INT)(FK)

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm()
        {
        var f=document.forms["reg"]["team"].value;
    
        if ((f==null || f==""))
          {
          alert("All Field must be filled out");
          return false;
          }
        }
        </script>
        <form name="reg" action="user_exec.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        <table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
          <div align="center">
            <?php 
          $remarks=$_GET['remarks'];
          if ($remarks==null and $remarks=="")
          {
          echo 'Register a new user';
          }
          if ($remarks=='success')
          {
          echo 'Registration Success';
          }
          ?> 
             </div></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><div align="right">Team:</div></td>
            <td>
     <?php
        $mysqli_hostname = "localhost";
    $mysqli_user = "root";
    $mysqli_password = "my_pass";
    $mysqli_database = "my_db";
    $prefix = "";
    $bd = mysqli_connect($mysqli_hostname, $mysqli_user, $mysqli_password) or die("Could not connect database");
    mysqli_select_db($mysqli_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
     
$sql = "SELECT idTeam,teamName FROM teamtable ";
     
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
    
     echo "<select name='team'>";
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['idTeam'] ."'>" . $row['teamName'] ."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
    </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><div align="right"></div></td>
            <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Please take a few minutes of your time to read up on the [stackoverflow/tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour), we are here to help, not just feed you code...

Comment: @Naruto i am not asking to feed me code ! I tried everything but the code isnt working. You can see the code that I tried. I am asking for help. If you cant help me out then please dont reply absurdly. Try other questions. Thanks.

Comment: Improve your question.. What's the result you are getting, what errors, what have you tried, what's failing, ... Basically what it says now is: why isn't my code working, which is also closeable... That's why I wanted you to read the tour :)

Comment: What is the actual question? I get what you want, but I don't know what you are expecting from us?

Comment: @Naruto 
I have fixed it myself. Thanks. :)

Comment: you said you fixed it yourself. Can you post that and share this knowledge. Thx.

Comment: Thank you. And best to make that into an Answer below. It is ok to Answer your own question, plus it can get upvotes and points for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 <?php
    include('connection.php');

$sql = "SELECT idTeam, teamName FROM team";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<select name='team'>";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['idTeam'] ."'>" . $row['teamName'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Just a small comment: put some explanation what is different from your original  question, what failed and what you did to solve.. Than you have the perfect answer ;)